# How to connect to end points in two linked series in HighCharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to connect the red solid line and the red dashed line.

However, if I use "linkedto" command in highchart, there will be a gap between to segments (http://jsfiddle.net/znvkh14o/)

```
$(function () {
    s1 = [
        [1246752000000, 21.4],
        [1246838400000, 21.3],
        [1246924800000, 18.3],
    ];
    s2 = [
        [1247024800000,20.5],
        [1247824800000,17.9],
    ];


$('#container').highcharts({
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime'
    },
    tooltip: {
        crosshairs: true,
        shared: true
    },
    series: [{
        name: 's1',
        data: s1,
        dashStyle : 'solid'
    }, {
        name: 's1',
        data: s2,
        linkedTo: ':previous',
        dashStyle : 'shortdot'
    }]
});
```

});

If I create a point to force them to be connected, the value of the points will be shown twice in the tooltips

```
$(function () {
    s1 = [
        [1246752000000, 21.4],
        [1246838400000, 21.3],
        [1246924800000, 18.3],
    ];
    s2 = [
        [1246924800000,18.3],
        [1247024800000,20.5],
        [1247824800000,17.9],
    ];


$('#container').highcharts({
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime'
    },
    tooltip: {
        crosshairs: true,
        shared: true
    },
    series: [{
        name: 's1',
        data: s1,
        dashStyle : 'solid'
    }, {
        name: 's1',
        data: s2,
        linkedTo: ':previous',
        dashStyle : 'shortdot'
    }]
});
```

});

Is there a way to solve this kind of problem?

Or is that possible to draw a line with two different line style?

A simplified version of my code is available in http://jsfiddle.net/5uyd1wmy/

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a 3rd serie connecting the 2 other.
This new serie needs to have mouse tracking disabled, show in legend set to false, and marker disabled.

```
{
    data: s3,
    enableMouseTracking: false,
    showInLegend: false,
    marker: {
        enabled: false
    },
    color: "#3399FF"
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/znvkh14o/1/